# Wordpress dbdelta a semicolon

Tags: wordpress

Ok i have query something like this

```
$drzava ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`wp_drzava` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Kod` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Naziv` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `NazivSrb` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `NazivSrbGenetiv` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `jePrevedeno` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `jeDrzava` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `PhoneCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NazivRo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=304 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO wp_drzava VALUES ('249', 'RO', 'Romania', 'Rumunija', 'Rumunije', null, '1', '+40', 'Rom&#226;nia ')";
```

Problem seems to be in România record, so i get not record inserted. I try dbDelta() function and also $wpdb->query() but i get no result. Can someone help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is

```
$drzava = array();
$drzava[] ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`wp_drzava` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Kod` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Naziv` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `NazivSrb` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `NazivSrbGenetiv` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `jePrevedeno` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `jeDrzava` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `PhoneCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NazivRo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=304 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;"

$drzava[] ="INSERT INTO wp_drzava VALUES ('249', 'RO', 'Romania', 'Rumunija', 'Rumunije', null, '1', '+40', 'Rom&#226;nia ')";
```

So we must insert array into dbDelta function!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO wp_drzava(ID, Kod, Naziv, NazivSrb, NazivSrbGenetiv, jePrevedeno, jeDrzava, PhoneCode, NazivRo) VALUES ('249', 'RO', 'Romania', 'Rumunija', 'Rumunije', null, '1', '+40', 'Rom&#226;nia ')";
```

Comment: what? there is no problem in query

Comment: Just change query to get_col

Comment: i find solution see answer